# Custom "fengyuanchen/datepicker" output

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I'm using fengyuanchen/datepicker
I'm trying to export the data (Month name, Day name, and day date)
to look like this : 
[image: custom output]


I found the options, however I'm unable to populate them correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<div data-toggle="datepicker" class=" docs-date input-date-picker-from">
  <div class="month" id="putMonthName">January</div>
  <div class="date">5</div>
  <div class="day" id="putDayName">Tuesday</div>
</div>
```

Simply I want the dates to be populated in the responding div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by overriding the pick callback.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
        autoPick: true,
        pick: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var pickedDate = e.date;              
            var month = $(this).datepicker('getMonthName');
            var date = e.date.getDate();
            var day= $(this).datepicker('getDayName');
            $(".month").html(month);
            $(".date").html(date);
            $(".day").html(day);
            $(this).datepicker('hide'); 
        }
    });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<div data-toggle="datepicker" class=" docs-date input-date-picker-from">
  <div class="month" id="putMonthName">January</div>
  <div class="date">5</div>
  <div class="day" id="putDayName">Tuesday</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate !! thats exactly what I wanted ! :)
can you help me one last bit? I need by default for it to view today's date on intialize

Comment: I edited my answer. Just need to add autoPick: true which should allow the plugin pick the initial date automatically after initialized.

Comment: I already tried this, it doesnt work, try to change the MONTH or DAY from the picker, it doesn't append correctly afterwards

Answer (score -1):

Day and month are working fine with **autoPick: false,**